# Find the ratio of green to red circles for given patterns

Tags: visual, pattern, tiling

Just a small visual task.
Find the ratio of green to red circles, for infinite planes, filled with the following patterns:

[image: pattern image in question]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a puzzle., merely a counting exercise.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - Not really.  I'm assuming OP meant infinite plane.  The question is whether there's more to it then just a textbook math problem.

Comment: It's still just a counting exercise to count how many circles of each colour there are on a tile, where a tile is any repeating section of the infinite pattern (which in this case can be the whole picture).

Comment: Well, if I change pattern a way, one couldn't solve problem by counting (it will not be a tiling then), would it solve the issue?

Comment: Done, patterns now larger and one can't  get (exact) answer with counting (though still get a good guess).

Comment: @ChrisCudmore, well, the meaning of this task is surprizing (in my humble opinion) result. Is it obvious to you that the second answer is _not_ 1/1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ratios are:

> 1:1 for the first pattern.
>  3(green):4(red) for the second pattern.

Because:

> The boxed regions below tile the plane with the required patterns, and have green/red counts of 6/6 and 6/8 respectively.
>  [image: Two patterns, with repeating region highlighted]

Alternatively:

> Counting the circles around each hexagon:
>
>  For the first pattern, we have six green circles at the corners, but each corner is shared by three hexagons. Plus one green circle in the centre, so we have 6/3 + 1 = 3 green circles per hexagon in total.
>  And we have six red circles on the edges, but each edge is shared by two hexagons, so we have 6/2 = 3 red circles per hexagon.
>  Giving us a ratio of 3:3 = 1:1
>
>  For the second pattern, we have the same number of green circles, but have an extra red circle in the centre of each hexagon, giving us a ration of 3:4.

Comment: Congrats, it is it, hope you enjoyed!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was not supposed to be very challenging, the reason I found this amusing and posted, is surprise vs intuitive answer, for second pattern, may be it is only me.

> Here is my own addition, as you can see below, for second pattern greens and reds both are tiled plane with triangles, so we can get answer from triangle areas ratio.

> [image]

P.S. May be, somebody interested in `svg` code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g transform="scale(0.6)" stroke-width="2" fill="none">
    <g id="M2">
    <g id="M1">
      <g id="M0">
          <g id="R2">
              <g id="R1">
                <circle id="Rp" cx="60" cy="23" r="8" stroke="red"/>
                <use xlink:href="#Rp" transform="translate(120)"/>  
              </g>
              <use xlink:href="#R1" transform="translate(60,35)"/>
          </g>  
          <use xlink:href="#R2" transform="translate(0,70)"/>      
          <g id="P21">
                <g id="P2">
                    <g id="P1">
                      <circle id="Pg" cx="20" cy="23" r="20" stroke-width="1" stroke="lightgray"/>
                      <use xlink:href="#Pg" transform="translate(20,35)"/>
                    </g>
                    <use xlink:href="#P1" transform="translate(40)"/>  
                </g>
                <use xlink:href="#P2" transform="translate(0,70)"/>
                <g id="B2">
                  <g id="Bp">
                    <circle cx="20" cy="23" r="8" stroke-width="3" stroke="white"/>
                    <circle id="Bp" cx="20" cy="23" r="8" stroke="green"/>
                  </g>
                  <use xlink:href="#Bp" transform="translate(40,70)"/>
                </g>  
          </g>
          <use xlink:href="#P21" transform="translate(80)"/>
          <use xlink:href="#P21" transform="translate(160)"/>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#M0" transform="translate(0,140)"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#M1" transform="translate(240)"/>

    <g transform="translate(0,500)">
    <g id="Mx1">
      <g id="Mx0">
          <use xlink:href="#M0"/>
          <circle id="Rp" cx="60" cy="93" r="14" stroke="red"/>
          <circle id="Rp" cx="180" cy="23" r="14" stroke="red"/>
      </g>
      <use xlink:href="#Mx0" transform="translate(0,140)"/>
    </g>
    <use xlink:href="#Mx1" transform="translate(240)"/>
    </g></g>
    <use xlink:href="#M2" transform="translate(480)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#M2" transform="translate(480,140)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#M2" transform="translate(0,140)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry for being a bit harsh on your original post. I do love tilings, and maybe it is my [familiarity with the subject](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/) that I just didn't see much of a puzzle element in your question. I like your observation about the areas here, and your svg code may very well be useful to me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the good word, I then was grieved a little, but mostly glad for the feedback and opportunity to improve the question, and now I'm just glad. Bookmarked your site: I am interested in tiling application to neural network internals, precisely in "linear" mappings of one tiling to another, for example, to change data tensor, representing image from standard "squared" to "hexagonal". Thats how I found the thing for this topic. But now I trying to implement smoothier tensor downsampling, from standart 4->1 to 2->1 + 2->1 using intermediate chess-like pattern.